# sqlalchemy create_all gives error that table exists

Tags: sqlalchemy

I am getting a new error using sqlalchemy. My Python code ran OK until recently (due to an update?). But now, when I execute metadata.create_all() I get an error that a table exists. I'm wondering why that happens since I thought create_all() should check to see if a table exists prior to attempting to create the table and there should be no such errors? I had tried metadata.create_all(checkfirst=True) and still get the error that the table exists. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please include a full stacktrace of the error you receive in your question

Comment: Thanks for your response! Not sure how to provide the stacktrace because this chat interface claims it's too long. Is there a way to attach a file?

Comment: Here is a much abbreviated error output:sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1050, "Table 'Device_Template' already exists")
[SQL: 
CREATE TABLE `Device_Template` (
 mask_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
 base_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
 hierarchy_level INTEGER NOT NULL, 
 relative_x INTEGER, 
 relative_y INTEGER, 
 size_x INTEGER, 
 size_y INTEGER, 
 relative_probe_ ..................

]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)

Comment: you can edit your original question to add the stack trace. Can you also edit your question to include a snippet of the actual code you've written? According to https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.create_all, the `create_all` method should check for existing tables by default (`checkfirst=True`). It sounds like that's not happening. Are you by any chance explicitly setting this to `False`?

Comment: Hi, I've explicitly set the checkfirst=True flag to no effect.